# Dming someone outside of the server discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I am trying to add a command to my bot which can dm someone a message. So I was wondering if it is possible to dm someone outside of a server where the bot doesn't reside?

Comment: if the member has no server common with the client, the client will fail to send message.

Comment: The bot needs to fetch the user from discord's cache and it will fail to fetch it if they do not share any server, this is not possible to do.

Comment: @Shunya you can still get user information of someone you do not share a server with. E.g. old messages from former guild members in the guild. It is by design that you cannot message users you don't share any server with.